# A variable with quotes as a sed command produces an error

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

I have this script:

```
num='[0-9]'
sedcmd='-e "s/${num}/as df/g"'
echo 123 | sed -r $sedcmd
```

The last line produces this:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a variable to store shell commands, use an array. See [BashFAQ-50  I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

You just use an array as below

```
num='[0-9]'
argArray=('-e' "s/${num}/as df/g")
```

and double-quote the array expansion to not let the words be split by Word-splitting and call as

```
echo 123 | sed -r "${argArray[@]}"
```